# How to get list of files from web URL outside my web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using `ASP.NET 4.5` with `C#`.

I have created a `web API` that **points** to the **folders out of my web-application** to get some shared resources. Now, I want to *retrieve the list of files* from the directory to which the web-api call points.

For example, my web application is resides on my local hard-drive's `F:\Projects\Web1` directory. I have placed some images in `C:\SharedRes\images` directory. I have created a `web-api` that fetches images from this shared directory. For e.g. `http://localhost/api/images/a.jpg` will get the `a.jpg` from `C:\SharedRes\images` directory. It is working fine, but I want to get the **list of files** from `C:\SharedRes\images` whenever I make a call to `web-api` like `http://localhost/api/images`.

I have tried following :

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("http://localhost/api/images"));
FileInfo[] file = directoryInfo.GetFiles().Where(f => f.Extension == (".bmp") || f.Extension == (".jpg") || f.Extension == (".png") || f.Extension == (".TIFF") || f.Extension == (".gif")).ToArray();
```

But it gives `URI format not supported` error.

Please let me know if any solution.

Comment: No experts available now-a-days on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 2):

[HttpServerUtility.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) method gets **virtual path** as parameter.

You should use `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/api/images")`

Comment: Thanks Volkan but no up-vote for this answer as this will give you the path of directory where your web-application resides. In my case the return path should be "C:\SharedRes\images", while your solution returns "F:\Projects\Web1\images". I had tries all these things using Server.MapPath() before posting my question. Since this is not working, I must down vote this solution.

Comment: If you make the "C:\SharedRes\images" folder virtual path from IIS, Server.MapPath gives you the right folder.

Comment: **1.** Delete the images folder from "F:\Projects\Web1\"

**2.** In IIS, right click "api" and 'Add Virtual Directory', give the alias "images" and physical path as "C:\SharedRes\images"
-
This should work, I have used it before.

Comment: OK. But I don't want to use this solution unless I found some other way to get it as the path of folder is dynamic and it can be a hurdle for deployment too.

Comment: The trick here is starting the string with "/" instead of "~/". 
With "~/" it gets folder under the directory that project's lies in. But when we start it with only "/", then it gets the virtual directory.
Thanks. It really helped.

Answer (score 1):

You Can simply use `Directory` class with it's `GetFiles` method to do so. The following code is for getting all files in `C:\SharedRes\images\` directory:

```
string[] _Files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\SharedRes\images\");
if (_Files != null && _Files.Count() > 0)
{ 
  FileInfo _file;
  string   _fileName="";

  foreach (string file in _Files)
  {
       _file = new FileInfo(file);
       _fileName = _fileName + @"<br/>" + _file.Name;
  }

Response.Write(_fileName);
```